# Javascript : how could i get callee id in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How could I get callee id in javascript

I am creating dynamic gridview from .cs adding templates to gridview as per requirement. In which first headercolumn is having checkbox. I wanted to call javascript function on click , here I want callee checkbox id in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want the source of the click event. Make sure the event is sent in the clickhandler (as in `onclick="myClickHandler(event)"`), then:

```
function myClickHandler(evt){
  var sourceElement = evt.srcElement || evt.target;
  /* do things */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the browser.

Microsoft will use window.event.srcElement to handle a reference to the object that fired an event.

W3C support browsers will pass the reference as an argument to the event handler.

Try [this.](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html)

Comment: thanks,i got the checkbox element. what could be done if need id?

Comment: once you have a reference to the element you can use it like any other reference. element.id or element.getAttribute("id")