# new Ajax Request onComplete of every Ajax Request

Tags: ajax, prototypejs

I'm using Prototype 1.7,  what I want is to run a new Ajax Request onComplete of every Ajax Request.  But I don't want the Ajax Request run on the 2nd request.

Like this:

AJAX Request Made (Request #1)
+-- Run Request onComplete onComplete of Request #1 (Request #2)
+---- Do NOT run request onComplete of Request #2

AJAX Request Made (Request #3)
+-- Run Request onComplete of Request #3 (Request #4)
+---- Do NOT run request onComplete of Request #4

I know I can do this:

```
    Ajax.Responders.register({
                        onCreate: function() { 
                        },
                        onComplete: function() {
                            new Ajax.Request('/update_active.php');
                        },
                        onUninitialized: function () {
                        },
                         });
```

The problem is the above creates an endless loop of Ajax Requests.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Thanks,
-David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a custom option property on the responder-invoked ajax request, and then check for that, before you send the next request:

```
Ajax.Responders.register({
    onComplete: function(transport) {
        if( typeof transport.options.isResponder !== 'undefined' ) {
            return; // don't start a new request if the custom option is set
        };

        // set the custom option so this request won't trigger another one
        new Ajax.Request('url', {
            isResponder: true 
        });
    }
});
```

You only need to set the option for the responder-triggered request. All other requests can remain unchanged

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [callee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068673/javascript-how-could-i-get-callee-id-in-javascript) of the request and abort if it is coming from itself.